# Stop .blur() function from triggering on select statement but remain on span

Tags: javascript, jquery, blur

I am trying to create an inline edit function to trigger differently on different elements.

I have tried to use other plugins but haven't been able to get them to do exactly what I want so have decided to try to create a plugin of my own, while learning jquery along the way.

The issue I am currently having is that I have a .blur event that is triggering on a span element correctly and this is what I want but when the element is a select element I don't want the blur event to trigger. As the code is below the blur event triggers and it is not the desired result. Can anybody advise how I can only trigger the blur() event on span elements and nothing else

```js
$('.inlineEdit-jmc').inlineEditJmc({
    fieldsArray: {
        table-column1: 'field-table-column1',
        table-column2: 'field-table-column2'
        }
});

(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.inlineEditJmc = function(options) {
        //Set Default Settings
            console.log(options);
            var settings = $.extend({
            'pk': null,
            'table': null,
            'field': null,
            'url': null,
            'type':  null,
            'fieldsArray': null
        },options)
        if(settings.fieldsArray == null){}else{
            var fields = new Array();
        }
        
        function load_settings(this_selected){
            settings['pk'] = this_selected.attr("data-pk"); // pk of table to be updated
            settings['table'] = this_selected.attr("data-table"); // table name of table to be updated
            settings['field'] = this_selected.attr("data-field"); // name of the field in the table being updated
            settings['url'] = this_selected.attr("data-url"); // url for the ajax call to be sent to.
            settings['type'] = this_selected.attr("data-type"); // type of input being used. Input or Select
            settings['value'] = this_selected.text(); //
            settings['class'] = this_selected.attr("class"); // The Class
            console.log(settings['table'] +' '+ settings['value']+ ' '+ settings['class']);
            // if there are optionional inserts passed lets grab them                                   
            console.log('passed options:');
            if(settings.fieldsArray == null){}else{
                //var fields = [];
                $.each(settings.fieldsArray,function(k,v){
                    //console.log('settings['+k+'] '+this_selected.attr(v));
                    $obj={};
                    $obj[k] = this_selected.attr(v);
                    fields.push($obj);
                });
            }
                                               
                                               
        }
 
        $(this).on('mouseover', function(event) {
            $(this).addClass("ui-state-hover");
        }).on('mouseout', function(event) {
            $(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover");;
        });
             
        if($(this).is('select')){
            $(this).on('change', function(){
                alert('changed');
                alert($(this).val());
                //console.log($(this));
                //load_settings($(this));

                var nt = $(this).text();
                var jsonstring = JSON.stringify(fields);
                // AJAX 
                
            });
        }
        if($(this).is('span')){
             $(this).on("blur", function () {
                alert('span');
                load_settings($(this));
                var nt = settings['value']
                console.log('comment: '+settings['value']);
                // we are going to update the db here.
               console.log('Insert');
               console.log(fields);
               var jsonstring = JSON.stringify(fields);
               console.log(jsonstring);

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: settings['url'],

                    data: {
                        fieldsArray: fields,
                        pk: settings['pk'],
                        table: settings['table'],
                        field: settings['field'],
                        value: settings['value']
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(data,status){
                                    console.log(data);
                    }

                });

            });
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td class=''>
    <select class='inlineEdit-jmc' ><option value='0' data-pk='3' data-url='/path/to/js/ajax/ajax.php' data-table='mysqltablename' data-field='ignore'>NO</option>
    
    <option value='1' data-pk='3' data-url='/path/to/js/ajax/ajax.php' data-table='mysqltablename' data-field='ignore' selected>YES</option>
    </select></td>
    
    
<td class=''><span class='inlineEdit-jmc' id='input' data-pk='3' data-url='/path/to/js/ajax/ajax.php' data-table='mysqltablename' data-field='comment' contenteditable='true'>Text that can be edited</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code section in place of yours that begins `if($(this).is('span')){
             $(this).on("blur", function ()`

```
$("span").on("blur", function () {
  // your function content here
});

$("span select").on("blur", function () {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

The two alternative selectors act like a case statement in jQuery

Comment: This looks to have worked. Thanks so much. Just changing $(this) to ('span') for the on blur has done the trick. Now I just need to get my head around why.

Comment: it worked but I cant upvote as I don't have enough reputation as yet. Thanks again I appreciate it.